# Discord Bot - AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'commands'

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm attempting to create a new Discord bot, and an issue occurs when trying to create a message that is announced to all Discord Servers the bot is currently in.

I have attempted to solve the problem to no avail, this includes looking it up, reading documentation, and of course trying new code.

```py
import discord
import asyncio 
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

TOKEN = [REDACTED]



# client = discord.Client()

client = Bot("!")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
        @client.command(pass_context=True)
        async def broadcast(ctx, *, msg):
                for server in bot.guilds:
                    for channel in server.channels:
                        try:
                            await channel.send(msg)
                        except Exception:
                            continue
                        else:
                            break
```

I expect the program to send my message to all servers the bot is currently in.

Ex: !hello Hi there, this is an announcement!

Should trigger the message following !hello to be broadcasted on every server there is.

**EDIT: After some help, I'm still having an issue! The error now is that nothing appears even after doing the command, and if I do it again, it comes up with an error: "Command broadcast is already registered."**

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use a `client.command` inside of a `client.event` like that?

Just use command instead:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def hello(ctx, *, msg):
    for server in client.servers:
        for channel in server.channels:
            try:
                await client.send_message(channel, msg)
            except Exception:
                continue
            else:
                break
```

This will send the message to the **first** channel in guild where the bot has **permission to send** messages.

For future references consider upgrading to the latest API version since old ones are NOT supported and you will get a hard time getting help. For the new API the code would look like this:

```
@client.command()
async def hello(ctx, *, msg):
    for server in bot.guilds:
        for channel in server.channels:
            try:
                await channel.send(msg)
            except Exception:
                continue
            else:
                break
```

Edit: As per comment from Patrick your specific error indicates that you're using `Client` instead of `Bot` , if so just use `@bot.command` instead.

Comment: The only thing I would add to this is that the error they're seeing indicates that they're using `Client` instead of `Bot`

Comment: Ye just saw that the error is in the title :/ thanks for the heads up @PatrickHaugh

Comment: @PatrickHaugh 

If I use 'Bot' , I get: "NameError: name 'Bot' is not defined"

I have client defined as: "client = discord.Client()"

This should work right? I still get the same error :(

Comment: No.  Use `from discord.ext.commands import Bot`, then `client = Bot("!")`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Thank you for trying to help, I'm still struggling! I have updated my original post with the full script with all the changes.